# To Check Whether Dynamic CheckBox is checked or not using js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic Checkbox and i want to check whether a checkbox is checked or not .When i Check or Uncheck First Checkbox it works Good.If i uncheck remaining checkbox it alerts Checked.Pls help me to overcome this issue.

**JQUERY**

```
function CheckRow(ProjectID, BID, LID, PID, ImageID, StatusID) {
    if ($("#chkProjectID").prop('checked') == true) {
        alert('checked');
        Checked(ProjectID, BID, LID, PID, ImageID, StatusID);
    } else {
        alert('Unchecked');
        Unchecked(ProjectID, BID, LID, PID, ImageID, StatusID);
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkProjectID"  onclick="CheckRow(ProjectID=' + full.ProjectID + ',BID=' + full.BID+ ',LID=' + full.LID+ ',PID=' + full.PID+ ',ImageID=' + full.ImageID + ',StatusID=' + full.StatusID + ')" />
```

Comment: Can you provide fiddle for this?

Answer (score 2):

Its happening because your checking for first checkbox only. If you have multiple checkbox created dynamically and want to check if its checked or not then change your code as below :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkProjectID"  onclick="CheckRow(this, ProjectID=' + full.ProjectID + ',BID=' + full.BID+ ',LID=' + full.LID+ ',PID=' + full.PID+ ',ImageID=' + full.ImageID + ',StatusID=' + full.StatusID + ')" />

function CheckRow(_this, ProjectID, BID, LID, PID, ImageID, StatusID) {
       //it will check for current checkbox
       if ($(_this).prop('checked') == true) {
            alert('checked');
            Checked(ProjectID, BID, LID, PID, ImageID, StatusID);
        }
        else {
            alert('Unchecked');
            Unchecked(ProjectID, BID, LID, PID, ImageID, StatusID);
        }
}
```

Comment: Now all the checkbox alerts unchecked if i check the checkbox

Comment: have tried it and its working do you have any other issue?